# Analytical function using group by clause

Tags: sql

I want to group the data to certain level and then apply analytical function to get percentage contribution of this new level over a level above this:-

I have a table `Temp_analytic` data as follows. The data in this table follows heirarchy (portfolio and inv_num has one to many relation and inv_num and loan_num has one to many relationship.

Loan_num roll-up to Inv_num and inv_num further roll-up to Portfolio

So basic data in at loan level.
I will group the data to Investor level and would like to see percentage contribution of the each investor to portfolio

**Base data**

```
Loan_num    Inv_num portfolio   Balance
1111    1   A   10
2222    1   A   20
3333    1   A   30![enter image description here][1]
4444    2   A   40
5555    2   A   50
6666    2   A   60
7777    3   B   70
8888    3   B   80
9999    3   B   90
```

I am using an analytical function Sum over partition by portfolio

**Query**

```
select loan_num, inv_num, portfolio, balance, round(balance/sum(balance) over (partition by portfolio),4.2)*100 portfolio_perc
from Temp_analytic
order by portfolio
```

**Result**

```
LOAN_NUM    INV_NUM PORTFOLIO  BALANCE  PORTFOLIO_PERC
1111        1       A          10        4.76
2222        1       A          20        9.52
3333        1       A          30       14.29
4444        2       A          40       19.05
5555        2       A          50       23.81
6666        2       A          60       28.57
7777        3       B          70       29.17
8888        3       B          80       33.33
9999        3       B          90       37.50
```

So I am able to get the percentage contribution of a loan to the portfolio

If I try to calculate percentage contrbution of an INV_NUM to the portfolio. I am getting an error
"Not a group by function" using the below query which is obvious. What I want to know is can we roll-up or group by data to one level and apply analytical functions ( partitioning to a higher level) ?

```
select inv_num, sum(balance), round(balance/sum(balance) over (partition by portfolio),4.2)*100 portfolio_perc
from delete_srini 
group by inv_num
order by portfolio
```

what is the best way to do it

The results should look like this

```
INV_NUM  PORTFOLIO  BALANCE PORTFOLIO_PERC
1        A          60       28.60
2        A          150      71.40
3        B          240     100.00
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.  But, use a subquery to aggregate the data first and then use the analytic function:

```
select inv_num, portfolio, balance,
       round(balance/sum(balance) over (partition by portfolio),4.2)*100 as portfolio_perc
from (select inv_num, portfolio, sum(balance) as balance
      from Temp_analytic ta
      group by inv_num, portfolio
     ) ta
order by inv_num;
```

You can actually do this in one shot -- without the subquery.  But reading and writing queries with analytic functions and aggregation takes some getting used to:

```
select inv_num, portfolio, sum(balance) as balance,
       round(sum(balance)/sum(sum(balance)) over (partition by portfolio),4.2)*100 as portfolio_perc
from Temp_analytic ta
group by inv_num, portfolio
order by inv_num;
```